# backbone drag and drop - getting dropped data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, drag

I'm relatively new to programming and this is my first time posting on here, so sorry in advance if this isn't presented correctly.

I'm building a health tracker app with Backbone JS. I am retrieving data from the Nutritionix API and populating a view on the left side of the screen with that data. I want the user to be able to drag an item from the populated view and drop it in a view to the right in which case a calorie counter will increase. I also need that data to persist so that when the user closes and reopens the app their selected data in the view will remain the same.

I've implemented the drag and drop feature just fine. I am now trying to make it so that when the user drops an item from the left view into the right view a collection is created that only contains the data in the right view. I believe that I need to do this so I can persist the data. Right now, I am having trouble transferring the API data along into the right view. Here are the relevant code snippets:

appView:

```
var app = app || {};

var ENTER_KEY = 13;

app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#health-app',

urlRoot: 'https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/',

events: {
    'keypress': 'search',
    'click #clearBtn': 'clearFoodList',
    'drop .drop-area': 'addSelectedFood',
    // 'drop #selected-food-template': 'addSelectedFood'
},


initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(app.ResultCollection, 'add', this.addFoodResult);
    // this.listenTo(app.SelectedCollection, 'add', this.addSelectedFood);

    app.ResultCollection.fetch();
    app.SelectedCollection.fetch();
    this.clearFoodList()
},

addFoodResult: function(resultFood) {
    var foodResult = new SearchResultView({
        model: resultFood
    });
    $('#list').append(foodResult.render().el);
},

// addSelectedFood: function(selectedFood) {
//  // var selectedFoodCollection = app.SelectedCollection.add(selectedFood)
//  console.log(app.SelectedCollection.add(selectedFood))

// },

clearFoodList: function() {
    _.invoke(app.ResultCollection.toArray(), 'destroy');
    $('#list').empty();
    return false;
},

search: function(e) {
    var food;

    //When the user searches, clear the list
    if($('#search').val() === '') {
        _.invoke(app.ResultCollection.toArray(), 'destroy');
        $('#list').empty();
    }
    //Get the nutrition information, and add to app.FoodModel
    if (e.which === ENTER_KEY) {
        this.query =  $('#search').val() + '?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=be7425dc&appKey=c7abd4497e5d3c8a1358fb6da9ec1afe';
        this.newUrl = this.urlRoot + this.query;
    var getFood = $.get(this.newUrl, function(data) {
            var hits = data.hits;
            var name, brand_name, calories, id;
            _.each(hits, function(hit){
                name = hit.fields.item_name;
                brand_name = hit.fields.brand_name;
                calories = hit.fields.nf_calories;
                id = hit.fields.item_id;

             food = new app.FoodModel({
                name: name,
                brand_name: brand_name,
                calories: calories,
                id: id
            });
             //If the food isn't in the ResultCollection, add it.
             if (!app.ResultCollection.contains(food)) {
                 app.ResultCollection.add(food);
          }
            });
            food.save();
        });

    }

}
});
```

breakfastView:

```
var app = app || {};

app.BreakfastView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#breakfast',

attributes: {
    'ondrop': 'ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")',
    'ondragover': 'allowDrop(event)'
},

events: {
    'dragenter': 'dragEnter',
    'dragover': 'dragOver',
    'drop': 'dropped'
},

initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(app.SelectedCollection, 'change', this.addSelectedFood);

  },

render: function() {},

  addSelectedFood: function(selectedFood) {
   // var selectedFoodCollection = app.SelectedCollection.add(selectedFood)
  console.log(app.SelectedCollection.add(selectedFood))

 },

dragEnter: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
},

dragOver: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
},

dropped: function(ev) {
    var data = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  // console.log(app.SelectedCollection)
  this.addSelectedFood(data);
},


});

 new app.BreakfastView

SelectedCollection:
var app = app || {};

app.SelectedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: app.FoodModel,

localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('selected-food'),
})

app.SelectedCollection = new app.SelectedCollection();
```

Here's my repo also, just in case: https://github.com/jawaka72/health-tracker-app/tree/master/js

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Drag and drop has a lot of compatibility issues that I didn't want to deal with, so I personally went with [RubaXa/Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) which is plain js and works pretty well within its intended use-case. With Backbone, it becomes a little harder to deal with, but you can get away easily with simple lists.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thank you for your response.  I'll give your suggestion a shot, but the real issue I'm having isn't getting the actual dragging/dropping action to work, but rather getting specific model data from a list item when it's dropped into a separate view. I think I might need to reword my question. But thank you very much. I appreciate your help!

Comment: My point wasn't really meant to answer your question (i'd have wrote an answer instead), it's more of a warning, that rolling your own drag and drop logic won't be easy, compatibility wise. Good luck!